# how to make a program for calculating a fourier series

Tags: python, fourier-descriptors

I'm a guy just playing with Fourier series. I created a python program for it, but I don't know how to calculate the arms so that it finally draws specific shapes or images. Here is my program: https://github.com/KikiZC/Projekt-Tocky. thank you for any help you can give me

I tried making a program that uses math to calculate the points (a table in my program) to draw the shape but it doesn't work :(. but i scrap it so i have nothing now.

Comment: "it doesn't work" -- without a specific programming problem statement, it's unfortunately pretty difficult to help you. you might want to take a look at some external resources and tutorials on the subject first (such as [here](https://olgaritme.com/posts/drawing-with-the-fourier-series/index.html) and [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/59068/how-to-get-fourier-coefficients-to-draw-any-shape-using-dft) ). The general theory of Fourier series are a fascinating topic, but much too broad for a SO question.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.**"*